# Замена тегов через preg_replace

Tags: php

Нужно удалить `style="произвольный код;"` из текста статьи, тегы вырезал (заменял) таким способом

```
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'</iframe>'si", "</amp-iframe>", $row['full_story'] );
```

Подскажите, как удалить этот код регуляркой?

Comment: А вам точно нужно использовать регулярки? Посмотрите сюда: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @rjhdby Так он отредактировал сообщение и уточнил. Посмотри историю, я отвечал на первое

Comment: $str="<div style='DELETE'>123</div>";
print preg_replace('/ style=\'(.*)\'/',"",$str);

Comment: Если нужно то вам остается только кавычки в регулярке заменить.

Answer (score 0):

Будет полностью удалён атрибут *style="color:red;"*

```
$string = '<p style="color:red;">Некий текст</p>';

echo preg_replace('~\hstyle="[^"]+"~', '', $string);
```

Результат:

```
<p>Некий текст</p>
```

Comment: Тупо и в лоб пойдет. Но это нехорошее решение! Судя по запросу TC - ему нужно очистить стили. А если искомая конструкция находится в блоке `<pre>`, а если она находится в блоке `комментариев`? Предлагаемое решение "почикает" везде, где надо и где не надо!